# Changing text style on iOS does not appear until after text field loses focus (using Flex)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, text-size

In Flash Builder, on a flex mobile app for iOS, I have a text field that is supposed to have text that resizes to fill it. It works fine on the AIR simulator, but doesn't work on a device or the iOS simulator.

The output confirms that the text size is being changed, but it doesn't display as long as the textfield has the focus.

I added a button that changes the font size - that works fine, and displays changes immediately. the code works fine on android also, so this appears to be an iOS specific issue - text is not updated while the textfield is selected.

The code snippet is from the custom skin on the textfield. Doesn't render til deselect.

```
  textDisplay.setStyle("fontSize",oldfont+1);
  textDisplay.text = "Insert text here"
  hostComponent.invalidateSkinState();
  hostComponent.validateNow();
```

Button code (in same file as textField, not in the skin code, obviously). Renders immediately (including the resizing that is done by the code in the skin)

```
<s:Button click="inputField.text='Insert text here'"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you applying an embedded font to the TextField? AIR for iOS does not support custom fonts for input fields and this could be causing the issue.

Comment: No, just the default font. The problem was iOS was preventing us from creating a terrible feature - resizing text that someone is still trying to type. We created a hack solution to get around it - just defocus then refocus the textField every ten keystrokes

Comment: That's an interesting little factoid. I'll have to keep that in mind for my applications.

Comment: New discovery - iOS DOES allows resizing while the text field is selected; it's a problem with spark skin classes. We were building our custom skin off of the textarea skin. Possibly it's a problem with skins in general, but not sure how to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem: the skin class uses the native text field. In the case of iOS, this only loads font styles on initiation. We ended up not using a skin at all, and instead wrote everything through change handlers.